# Retrieve data stashed in service after resolve of promise AngularJS/ES6

Tags: javascript, angularjs, es6-promise

I have a service which gets data from the back end which returns as a promise. Once I resolve the promise I maintain the data within the service, but I'd like to get that saved data as many times as I want as soon as it is available.

```
module.factory
var dataStash = {};

var service = {
        getListData : getListData,
        returnDataByListname: returnDataByListname
    };
    return service;

    function getListData(listName){
        //...get the data corresponding to this list
        ).then(setData);

        function setData (data, listName){
            //store the data from the resolved promise as an
            //object attribute with name same as the list name
            dataStash.listName = data;
        }

    }//end getListData

function returnDataByListname(listName){
       //how best to do this??
        return dataStash.listName;
    }
```

Everything works fine but since I'm not returning the data as soon as the promise is resolved, but rather just saving it in the service, there is the issue of how soon I can call returnDataByListname. Since I don't know when the promise will be resolved and the data made available, how can I set up returnDataByListname so that it returns the data as soon as it is available after being called?

Comment: not sure what both do.. if returnDataByListname needs getListData to run first, then maybe call that from returnDataByListName and act upon the returned promise by only then returning dataStash.listName. You can create your own promise withing returnDataByListname which you can then use to wrap the call to getListData in.

Comment: Yeah getListData needs to be called before returnDataByListname, I wanted to avoid calling returnDataByListname from anywhere inside of getListData though. I was looking for a solution where once I have the data stored inside of the service, I can just return it anywhere the service is injected

Comment: I don't see how you would do that, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're primarily caching data, then `returnDataByListname` could return a promise:

```
function returnDataByListname(listName){
  return promiseStash[listName] || promiseStash[listName] = getListData(listName);
}
```

Then callers could call `returnDataByListname('foo').then(foo => console.log(foo));` repeatedly, yet `getListData('foo')` would only be called once.